# Git : getting content of a repository using only .git informations

Tags: git

I need to access to a git repository to get a project. A colleague gave me his .git directory of the project but without any other information.

According to the git bash console, the directory containing this .git is affiliated to a remote repository (the master mention).

```
MY@ID MINGW64 ~/R/projects/repos/proj_A (master)
$ ls -la
total 192
drwxr-xr-x 1 LB5553 1049089      0 Dec 20 11:36 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 LB5553 1049089      0 Dec 20 11:35 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 LB5553 1049089      0 Dec 20 11:54 .git/
-rw-r--r-- 1 LB5553 1049089 188521 Dec 15 14:35 git.zip
```

I can access to some information about the project (git branch, git status, git log) but if I try to clone, pull or fetch I can't download it.

> fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
>   remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.

So I understand I need to feed the URL of the git repository but I don't have it, I looked into the .git directory, [but I don't seem that this information is present there.](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/23/whats-inside-your-git-directory.html) Did I miss something? Is it possible to get the files of the project another way or do I have to contact my colleague to get access to the repository?

Thank you for your insights.

Comment: you didn't directly clone from repository

Comment: Try cloning from that .git folder.

Comment: No i didn't clone from the remote  repository, my colleague gave me the git.zip that contains his .git directory. And when I try to clone I get this fatal error.

Comment: But the ```git reset --hard``` solution from Daniel Mann seemed to worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `git reset --hard`. This will restore the contents of the filesystem to the current `HEAD`.

You haven't specified if you need to access the remote or just need the files; this will get you the files.

Comment: Perfect, thank you !
(I don't need to access to the remote repository, I will upload these files on another repos for another team... )

Answer (score 0):

"master" is not the name of a remote repository, that is the name of the current branch. It sounds like there isn't any remote configured for the repository. If you run `git remote` I think you'll see that the command prints nothing, indicating that there is no remote configured, and therefore you cannot use commands like `git pull` and `git fetch` because git doesn't know where you want to pull or fetch from.

Comment: Oh ok I see, I have these logs and informations about branches because of the .git directory and not because it is linked to the remote repository, right ?
Anyway, that ```git reset --hard``` solution seemed to work (the projects files appeared). I didn't need to establish a connection to the repos, I just needed to get the files so I could put them in another repository.

Comment: Yeah, `git log` would be reading data from the local `.git` directory. Glad the `git reset --hard` did what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

In the very first place, the way you've shared the repository with your colleague (copying the .git folder) isn't the right approach!

You should take the remote repository URL from your colleague and then run

```
git clone <URL>
```

in your system

In case your colleague isn't aware of the URL, he can run the

```
git remote show origin
```

command in his git repository, which displays the URL in the first couple of lines.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand why he only gave me this. But now that I have the files I can put them on a corporate git so we can share this properly.  Thank you though.

Answer (score -1):

the .git directory is already the repository structure!
When you clone a remote repository you download the whole .git + files into a local directory.

If your colleague gave you only the .git directory is not enough, because all concrete file, referenced in the .git folder are missing.